# Creating global API object

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, global

I'm using the module-via-anonymous-function-pattern in java-script to have an anonymous function that embodies the whole module and exposes specific public API parts by setting a global property.

I tried several methods of setting such a global property and the second one posted below fails:

```
window.foo = (function() {
  function bar() { this.hello = "world" }
  return new bar();
})();

> foo.hello
"world" // OK
```

vs.

```
(function() {
  window.foo2 = new bar( this.hello = "world" );
  function bar() {}
})();

> foo2.hello
undefined // Fail
```

Why is the second method not creating a proper bar-object?

Comment: Out of scope, you should return the object from the return block.

Comment: `new bar( this.hello = "world" )` looks strange.

Comment: pktangyue, yes, will have some coffee first... sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your 2nd method:

```
(function() {
  window.foo2 = new bar( this.hello = "world" );
  function bar() {}
})();
```

`this` is the `window`, and

```
new bar(this.hello = "world")
```

is equal to

```
window.hello = "world";
new bar(window.hello);
```

you can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/weH9b/2/)

And I think what you want is :

```
(function() {
  window.foo2 = new bar( "world" );
  function bar(a) {this.hello = a}
})();
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/weH9b/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you should try the code below

```
(function() {
  function bar() { this.hello = "world"; };
  window.foo2 = new bar();
})();
```

Comment: Uh, you're right.... But functions can be called before they are lexically defined, aren't they?

Comment: @hotzen but in your case in `this.hello = "world"` `this` is anonymous self executing function not the bar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way to use construct an object. Try this two ways.

```
window.foo2 = new bar();
function bar() {this.hello = "world";};
```

or

```
window.foo2 = new bar("world");
function bar(x) {this.hello = x;};
```

Comment: In you second case, the word "World" is stored in window.hello